# TSQL getting the maximum and minimum date for each person and his number

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a dataset like this:

[image]

It is necessary to getting the minimum and maximum date, the person and his number from each frame:

[image]

The code sample below: [enter link description here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=21b619275a3cb5ca292c2a2a27e36dbc)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So what's stopping you? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong screenshot by mistake.

Comment: Never mind the screenshots, most people here want formatted text anyway - not images.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a requirements document is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a gaps-and-islad problem. Here is one way to solve it using window functions:

```
select 
    min(person_date) person_date_start,
    max(person_date) person_date_end,
    person,
    number_one
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by person_date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by person, number_one order by person_date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by person, number_one, rn1 - rn2
```

It is quite unclear what is the logic to generate the `id` in the outer query. If you want to *renumber* the records, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select 
    row_number() over(order by min(person_date)) id,
    min(person_date) person_date_start,
    max(person_date) person_date_end,
    person,
    number_one
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would recommend the difference of row numbers for this:

```
select person, number_one, count(*) as cnt,
       min(person_date), max(person_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by person_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by person, number_one order by person_date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by person, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```